# JQuery access clicked element without using a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, closures

I'am trying to handle a simple JQuery click event like this

```
$('nav.menu a').on('click', function(){
   console.log($(this)); // returns the DOM element
});
```

But since I'd like to reuse the closure, I've change it to a normal function:

```
function myClickCallback(event, someParam){
    console.log($(this)); // returns the 'window' obj
}

$('nav.menu a').on('click', myClickCallback(event, someParam));
```

So the question is how do I access the clicked element from within the `myClickCallback` function

Comment: `$('nav.menu a').on('click', function(event){myClickCallback.call(this, event, someParam);});` ???

Comment: this works but I was wondering if it is possible to do it without wrapping my function in the anonimous function

Comment: You have to set relevant context in some way. I don't see better way if you have to pass some extra parameter to event handler

Comment: is there a way / does it make sense to pass the relevant context as function parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.target`

```
function myClickCallback(event){
    console.log($(event.target)); 
}

$('nav.menu a').on('click', myClickCallback);
```

If you want to pass a param to the function, you can use the transport mechanism of [event.data](http://api.jquery.com/on/). `event.data` contains the data parameter passed to `$.on` when the event handler function is called:

```
function myClickCallback(event){
    console.log('event on ' + $(event.target)); 
    console.log('param ' + event.data); 
}

$('nav.menu a').on('click', null, 'theParam', myClickCallback);
```

Comment: `event.target` can be different than `this`

Comment: yep, $(event.target) returns `document`, so it is not the clicked DOM element

Comment: @MirkoGuarnier did you use `$('nav.menu a').on('click', myClickCallback)`?

Comment: right, need to clearify a bit. using it without params returns the DOM element correclty, but I need a way to pass `someParam` to the function

Comment: Ya you could use `event.data` to pass extra parameter to event but again, in your second example, use `this`, not `event.target` which can be different than relevant orginal element firing the event, it could be any of its descendant

Comment: @A.Wolff `event.target` is the DOM element that initiated the event, `event.currentTarget` is the current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.

Comment: @wero Not always same element than the one on which event is bound, click span here: https://jsfiddle.net/8vj57ceh/  If element has no descendant (DOM node type), then it will always be the same but...

Comment: @A.Wolff now I understand your comment. Finally the use of `this` or `event.target` depends on application requirements. As the the OP @MirkoGuarnier never seems to accept answers to his questions, I will leave the discussion.

Comment: @wero I guess anyway you have fixed OP's expected behaviour passing extra param to event object, and set relevant context ( if using this :) ) so you get my vote

Comment: @A.wolff why so pissed with me ? I do accept answers when they do answer what I ask. If I don't accept an answer within 30 min I can do it later right ? So, if you move your comment as an answer I can accept it. Both answers fits my requirement so thanks both, I can accept who came first